# Getting POST or PUT to work in a WCF REST Service

Tags: c#, wcf, linq

I have a WCF Service and I am able to GET from it but I can’t work out how to PUT to it. I just want to increment a hits field each time the record is used in the client. Here is some of my code.

Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "IncSMS")]
void IncSMS();
```

Method:

```
public void IncSMS()
{
    var business =
        (from p in _db.Businesses
            where p.BusinessID == 1
            select p).FirstOrDefault();
    business.SMSHits += 1;
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I’m getting “Method not allowed.” In IE, can anyone see what I’m doing wrong???

Cheers,

Mike.

Comment: If you're doing a request in IE, wouldn't that do a get?  Have you tried to put with something like wfetch?

Comment: If people aren't going to handle the 'OrDefault' scenario, why don't they just use the First() function?

Comment: @LukeBaulch it defers the exception from occurring for *one more line*.

Comment: If I change the request to GET I get error 400 “The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.”

Comment: I can't make a PUT method work either. Keep getting method not allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I asked the question and it took me three days to find the answer to something that should have been very simple.

So the question ended up being: How do I add a `Content-Length` header to my request???

Answer: You can’t add `Content-Length` to a URI when typed into a browser, “because by default it will perform a GET”!!! To add `Content-Length` to your header you must use a debugging tool, e.g.. Fiddler or build a form or some other type of client!

In fiddler you simply type `Content-Length`: 0 in the “Request Headers” section of the “Request Builder” and it will magically work! As seen near the bottom of this tutorial: http://blog.donnfelker.com/2008/12/04/how-to-rest-services-in-wcf-3-5-part-2-the-post/

Thanks guys,

Mike.

Comment: Just noted that you have "ContACT-Length: 0".  You mean "Content-Length: 0" right?  Copied and pasted it and it did not work until a while later when I spotted the mistake

Answer (score 2):

*Method not allowed* generally means that, on the client side, you are using an HTTP method that does not match what you've configured in the WCF code. In your case you've specified PUT as the HTTP Method for that WCF -exposed service method.  It could be that you are using HTTP POST when your attribute says PUT.

If you use Fiddler, you will be able to see the request and response.  If the problem is as I've described, then when you send a POST, the raw response will look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: PUT
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 02:17:43 GMT
```

The "Allow" header in the response will tell you: Please use PUT.

Comment: Fiddler is giving me error 411 on both PUT and POST asking for ContentLength what is that all about??? Also I can’t see the result you’ve shown in  Fiddler, may because I have the free version???

Comment: Cheeso, I’m now getting the exact same results you mention above if I use POST istead of PUT and vice versa, but if I do it correctly I get “HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length” if I use GET, I get error 400 The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details, any ideas??? I’m fine with chuncking my request if need be…lol.

Comment: To diagnose the 411, you will need to describe your client-side approach for invoking the WCF Service. Are you using jQuery?  some other AJAX library?  Building the request yourself "manually"?  I suspect the solution is simple. You don't need chunking, you need only to add a `Content-Length` header to the request. The 411 seems to be complaining about that. You can see the request in Fiddler as well, and verify that the `Content-Length` header is missing.

Comment: Sorry Cheeso, I hadn’t notice your new response. I now know I have to add a Content-Length header to my request. I just don’t know how to do that. I am simply requesting the service method via a URI in the browser and again in Fiddler. So my question is now, how do I add a Content-Length header to my request??? Cheers, Mike.

Comment: Normally the content-length is computed and placed into the request automatically for you, by the HTTP communications library. This is why I asked you to describe your client-side approach for invoking this service. Show your code. If it is an HTTP POST, you cannot simply put the URI in the browser address bar; it will not work if you try that. Show your code for how you are invoking this service.

Comment: Those are URLs.  That's not code.  How does the application invoke the services?  where is the client-side code that connects to the service?

Comment: I wanted to test the service before building a client, I now know you cant do that with a browser. The code was working fine the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a `PUT`, try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which will let you build a request using any HTTP method, modify request headers, view response headers, etc.  Very useful for testing WCF services.

Comment: A few answers here, I’m guessing your all saying there is nothing wrong with the code, it should work, so something else must be wrong elsewhere?
Fiddler gives me the same error as IE 405 “Method Not Found”